# How to compute $\parallel f \parallel_{L_2(\mathbb{R}^2)}$ for $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+(x-y)^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, improper-integrals

So I want to compute $$\int\limits_\mathbb{R} \int\limits_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{(1+(x-y)^2)^2} dxdy.$$

As I understand, I cannot reduce it to $1$-dimensional integrals, since Fubini's theorem requires measure of whole space to be finite.

Thank you.

Comment: Fubini does not require that the measure of whole space is finite. For example when your function is of one sign, then you can apply it (so in your example it works)

Comment: Are you sure this is your integral? That function is not in $L^2(\Bbb R^2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrand is positive. Thus, you can use Fubini's theorem:
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \dfrac{1}{\left(1+(x-y)^2\right)^2} \mathrm{d}\lambda &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_\mathbb{R}\dfrac{1}{\left(1+(x-y)^2\right)^2} \mathrm{d}x \right)\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_\mathbb{R}\dfrac{1}{\left(1+u^2\right)^2} \mathrm{d}u \right)\mathrm{d}y \text{ by substitution } u=x-y \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} C\mathrm{d}y \\
&= +\infty
\end{align}
where $C >0$ is a constant

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac 1{(1+(x-y)^{2})^{2}} dx=\int_{\mathbb R} \frac 1{(1+t^{2})^{2}} dt $ which is independent of $y$ hence the integral w.r.t $y$ is $\infty$. The function  does not belong to $L^{2}$.